# Using .ttf font file in Pillow within a django app hosted on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, fonts, python-imaging-library

I am setting up my first web application via the Django framework. This application takes data supplied by an html form and generates an image using Pillow. this image features text drawn on top of it, and I would like to use a particular .ttf file when generating the text. The font is used just fine when I run the app locally (via manage.py runserver), however, when running on Heroku an "OSError" occurs as it "cannot open resource".

## Location of font file in directories.

scales is the Django root folder. scales1 is a package I wrote containing image generation logic. The scales_app folder contains the view for which the image is generated.

scales/AGENCYB.ttf

scales/scales1/AGENCYB.ttf

scales/static/fonts/AGENCYB.ttf

scales/scales_app/AGENCYB.ttf

The Heroku app builds just fine and can be visited via web browser.
https://guit-proj-1.herokuapp.com/scales/SelectBoard

Clicking the "Gen Board" button will elicit the traceback below. Note that the application was fully functional when the default font for pillow was used. However, the font did not look acceptable for my application.

I have tried placing the font file in all places where it might be relevant including the root directory of the Django app, the python package where the image generation logic is stored, and in a static/fonts/ directory.

## Attempt to import font

`agencyb = ImageFont.truetype("AGENCYB.ttf", 13)
 font = agencyb`

("/AGENCYB.ttf" was tried as the filename as well, only serving to break functionality of the app when run locally.)

## Traceback

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/app/scales_app/views.py" in GenBoard
  40.     img = scales.gen_board(scale, tunings)

File "/app/scales1/scales.py" in gen_board
  276.     img = draw_board(fretboard_w_scale)

File "/app/scales1/scales.py" in draw_board
  140.     arial = ImageFont.truetype("/AGENCYB.ttf", 13)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py" in truetype
  546.         return freetype(font)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py" in freetype
  543.         return FreeTypeFont(font, size, index, encoding, layout_engine)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py" in **init**
  161.                 font, size, index, encoding, layout_engine=layout_engine

Exception Type: OSError at /scales/GenBoard
Exception Value: cannot open resource

Comment: Note: the scales directory is also the git directory pushed to Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by ensuring that the file path was specific to the Heroku environment.

agencyb = ImageFont.truetype("/app/AGENCYB.TTF", 13)